# Convert hex to ASCII, like in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am looking for a function in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) which will convert a hex value to the corresponding ASCII, like in Excel.

For example, in Excel,

```
 =CHAR(HEX2DEC("c7")) will return, 'Ç'
```

Is there any library function, which does the same, in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim hexValue = "FF"
Dim ascii = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexValue, 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a byte array to an ASCII string using [`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx). The byte array can be defined using hex literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ChrW` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chrw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You have to import the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace:

```
ChrW(Convert.ToInt32("C7", 16))
```